# A question about Kronecker pairing

Tags: algebraic-topology

> **Corollary 2.31**. If $R$ is a field, $M$ is a vector space over $R$, and $C_*$ is a chain complex over $R$, then
> $$H^q\left({C_*;M}\right) \cong \operatorname{Hom}\left({H_q\left({C_*}\right),M}\right)$$
>
> Moreover the Kronecker pairing is nondegenerate. $\square$

I am stuck on why the Kronecker pairing here is non-degenerate?

Comment: What is this a corollary *of*?

Comment: @NoahSchweber universal coefficient theorem for cohomology

Comment: The map $h : H^q(C_*; M) \to \text{Hom}(H_q(C_*), M)$ in UCT takes a cocycle $\varphi$ to the Kronecker pairing, $\langle \varphi, - \rangle$. This is an isomorphism if and only if the pairing is non-degenerate.